# C++ Append Continuation chain from function in UI thread

Tags: c++, concurrency, windows-runtime, task, winrt-async

Is there a way to send a continuation chain (that i created in some function)  to another function and append it there? 
like

```
IAsyncAction^ SomeClass::func1 () {
    return create_async([this]() 
{
    create_task([]() {doTheFirstStuff();}).then([]() {doTheSecondStuff();});
});
}
```

and then

```
void func2 () {
create_task(someObject->func1()).then([](){doTheLastStuff();}
```

I know this is wrong, because func2 will create the task and will execute "doTheLastStuff()" even before "doTheSecondStuff()" finished. But how can i archieve that this is not the case and that everything is done in the right order?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `return`ing the task you create,

Answer (score 0):

The WinRT Async abstractions (IAsyncAction^) don't have the concept of a chain of async steps so once you convert to those (using create_async) you won't be able to.

That said I'm not sure if a concurrency::task<> supports appending to it either; lookup the methods on task<> to see what it supports.